# change width of a view according to content in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode6, xib, xcode-storyboard

The question may look duplicate but please consider my scenario. In my xib file I added a view. Inside the view I added 3 imageview that are horizontally aligned. For some condition the imageViews will show/hide like below:

if(string=="1st") firstImage.hidden=true

else if(string=="2nd") secondImage.hidden=true

Now if one or two image is made hidden then I want to change the width of the view according to the content width. So how to set this in xib file. I'm using xcode6 & swift for my project

Comment: You'd probably have to do this with code.

Comment: isn't there any "wrap_content" property like android layout??

Comment: considering using autolayout. You will have to implement a constraint of width, and in the code, at certain time, you will set the constant of that constraint to 0. It will take you a day or two if you haven't known anything about Autolayout, but it's totally worthy.

Comment: @ FlySoFast. thanks for the suggestion. That might be the thing that I need to use. Will definitely give it a try